# How to disable text selection using jQuery Splitter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate the [jQuery Splitter](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.splitter) plugin into a web page. There are 2 "panels" (leftDiv and rightDiv):

```
  <div id="mainDiv" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
      <div id="leftDiv">
          left
      </div>
      <div id="rightDiv">
          right
      </div>
  </div>
```

The jQuery Splitter plugin is initialized with the following options:

```
$('#mainDiv').split({
    orientation:'vertical', limit:120, position:180
});
```

When I drag the splitter, the text in the right panel is highlighted. If I throw an image or canvas into the right panel it is also highlighted.

I have tried to apply the following CSS to the right panel but it doesn't seem to work:

```
#rightDiv{
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

I don't see anything in the splitter code that might help:

https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.splitter/blob/master/js/jquery.splitter.js

Maybe there's something I can to onDragStart to temporarily disable the text select and then re-enable onDragEnd. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not an issue in the splitter demo (http://jquery.jcubic.pl/splitter.php). Could you make a minimal working example snippet that reproduces this?

Comment: Like @BobBrinks mentioned. Please provide us with a JsFiddle. You at least need to provide the outer container for the mainDiv, because the 100% might be an invalid height for the splitter. In the docs there is this Note: **Note: You need to set the height of the container for splitter to work.**. So probably you try to set the height to 200px or another test value.

Comment: In what browser you see this behavior? I can't reproduce in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ch3hgfnh/2/ also which version of jQuery Splitter you're using?

Comment: @jcubic I am using version 0.21.0. I didn't realize I was out of date already. I upgraded to 0.23.0 and the issue is resolved. Please post an answer and I'll "accept" it. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with previous versions of jQuery Splitter and selecting text in the left pane but it was solved in recent version.